# Interesting Number Game

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let's say you are given some random positive integer. Next, assume you are given the following sequence of integers: $$[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].$$

Now, assume you are allowed to use the following moves: Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division. Note: multiplication or division by zero is not allowed.

Here's the game: you have to reduce the random positive integer down to $1$ by using your choice of moves. The catch is that you have to use every element in the sequence once and only once. For a concrete example, consider the following set of moves for the number $2752$:

$$2752 \div 8 = 344\ \ \ \ \ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]$$
$$344 - 1 = 343\ \ \ \ \ [2,3,4,5,6,7,9]$$
$$343 \div 7 = 49\ \ \ \ \ [2,3,4,5,6,9]$$
$$49 \times 4 = 196\ \ \ \ \ [2,3,5,6,9]$$
$$196 - 5 = 191\ \ \ \ \ [2,3,6,9]$$
$$191 - 2 = 189\ \ \ \ \ [3,6,9]$$
$$189 \div 9 = 21\ \ \ \ \ [3, 6]$$
$$21 \div 3 = 7\ \ \ \ \ [6]$$
$$7 - 6 = 1$$

I am curious about this sort of game.

I want to know for what integers will this game work? Clearly there is an upper bound, i.e. a maximum integer for which this game, as constructed, will work. In this case, that maximum integer is $ 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 + 1 = 362881$. However, surely not all integers up to $362881$ can be reduced to $1$ given the constraints of this game.

On the other hand, assuming the game always gives you a whole number to reduce, there should be an infinite number of sequences of integers for which that given whole number can be reduced to $1$ using the available moves. This comes from the fact that these whole numbers are, of course, algebraic numbers. However, for now let's assume the only sequence of integers we are allowed to use is $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$.

A weaker version of my question would be something like the following: Am I guaranteed to be able to reduce any 4-digit integer to $1$ using the constraints of this game? If not, then can I reduce any 3-digit integer? In general, is there a method other than brute force to find the greatest integer $x$ such that for all $N \leq x$, $N$ can be reduced to $1$?

Comment: This is just one example of a class of game that you see a lot, but which as far as I know isn't very well studied. Describing the span of a set under some operations tends to be quite easy, however, adding restrictions on how many times those operations can be done seems make the problem very difficult.

Comment: play game in reverse order, start from $1$ and reach all possible number by using $1,2,3,..,9$

Comment: Actually the maximum would be $2\cdot9!$.

Comment: $9!+1 = 9\times 8\times 7\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2 + 1 $

Comment: Oh, yes. Should be + 1. I will correct that.

Comment: Are you allowed to have non-integer values as intermediate results?

Comment: Nope. For now I'm interested in the case where we're only dealing with positive integer values. However, adding in the rationals, for example, would be interesting.

Comment: @mesel playing the game in reverse seems like an obvious choice. However, that requires constructing each individual number, and what I'm really interested in knowing is whether there exists some mathematical machinery to find, in general, the greatest integer _x_ such that for all _N_ less than or equal to _x_, _N_ can be reduced to 1 by the rules of the game.

Comment: One thing that stands out, for me at least, is that it's not immediately clear how whether or not one number $x$ is attainable gives any real information about whether or not some number $y$ is also attainable. So, even if we were given the minimum unattainable number for free, it's not clear how a non-brute force solution would be able to show that every smaller positive integer is attainable.

Comment: @DennisMeng that echoes my feeling. I'm not convinced, or at least I cannot myself imagine, that there's any mathematical technology that could be used to yield information about whether some number _y_ is reducible given only that _x_ is reducible.

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is some sort of probabilistic model.

Comment: It would also be interesting to find numbers with more than one solution. I bet there aren't many if any.

Comment: I was way wrong, there are a lot of collisions for almost any number. Here's all of the solutions for the list $[1, 2, 3, 4]$, where $1$ is the target: http://pastebin.com/zf1QZfED. The solutions for the range $[1, 7]$ was 341MB and the growth is exponential (or maybe worse), so I won't be pasting $[1, 9]$.

Comment: You'll notice that $38$ and $[41, 47]$ are missing and that $34$ and $39$ are unique.

Comment: Here's a list of all the numbers with no solution given the set $\{1, ..., 9\}$ (ie the original problem described in your question): http://pastebin.com/EqRaGk8u